# How to enable eslint caching?

Tags: javascript, npm, caching, eslint

I'm trying to enable eslint caching, following [this part of the user guide](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#caching)

My command is `npm run lint -- --cache=true`, and the lint script just runs a script that spawns `esw` (which itself just runs `eslint` — we have v7.x installed) as a child process.

From earlier in the user guide

```
Caching:
  --cache                         Only check changed files - default: false
  --cache-file path::String       Path to the cache file. Deprecated: use --cache-location - default: .eslintcache
  --cache-location path::String   Path to the cache file or directory
  --cache-strategy String         Strategy to use for detecting changed files in the cache - either: metadata or content - default: metadata
```

But when I run the command I get:

```
npm WARN invalid config cache=true
npm WARN invalid config Must be a valid filesystem path
```

Even supplying a `--cache-location=.eslintcache` doesn't change the error message.

How am I supposed to enable caching?

Answer (score 2):

This may be because of the order of the arguments your passing to your script. When you pass arguments in that fashion, they are appended to the arguments that already exist in your command. In this case, it means the --cache argument is getting added **after** the path of the files you're going to lint. It must come before. Simply modify your package.json to have it before like below:

```json
...
"scripts": {
   "lint": eslint --cache src
}
...
```

It will automatically save the cache to the root directory of your repository in a file called ".eslintcache"